# How to obtain statistics within a Buffer/Catchment in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, buffer, catchment-area

I need to calculate the population statistics within a 10 minute drivetime catchment from a point and within 1 Km Buffer from a point in MapInfo, how can I do that can someone please elaborate? I have a population thematic map and I have made a buffer on one location and I need to find the total population living within that area? I am also using a Drivetime addon with MapInfo for drive time catchments and Mapinfo to make Buffers.
Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should use the *Table > Update Column* command to calculate the population. Depending on how your population data is stored (point or polygon), how the dialog is filled out will differ:

In the examples:

*CatchPopn* is the attribute in the drivetime catchments table *DTCatch* that will receive the calculated population count

*PopnCol* is the population count attribute in the population source table *Population*

**Points**

- Table to update: DTCatch
- Column to update: CatchPopn
- Get value from table: Population
- Join: where object from table DTCatch contains object from table Population
- Calculate: Sum
- Of: PopnCol

**Polygons**

- Table to update: DTCatch
- Column to update: CatchPopn
- Get value from table: Population
- Join: where object from table DTCatch intersects object from table Population
- Calculate: ProportionalSum
- Of: PopnCol

You might also want to look up dasymetric areal interpolation techniques.